# Updating mysql database based on logical test

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update one database based on the data of another.

Basically the road no, the block no, and the building no are in both databases, but the one contains the lats and longs and  the other doesn't. So I am trying to update the lats and longs to the other.

Here is what I did.

```
<?php 

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("class") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE lat2='' And lon2 = ''"); // Selects from the database without lats and longs
 $address = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address ") // selects from database with lats and longs
 or die(mysql_error()); 


 while($infodata = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
    $infoaddress = (mysql_fetch_array($address));


    $BuildingA = $infoaddress['Building']; // A stands for Address where is the database address
    $RoadNoA = $infoaddress['RoadNo'];
    $BlockA = $infoaddress['Block'];

    $BuildingD = $infodata['Building']; // D stands for testData which is the same database
    $RoadNoD = $infodata['RoadNo'];
    $BlockD = $infodata['Block'];

    $idA = $infoaddress['id']; // ID for address
    $idD = $infodata['id']; // ID for Data

    $lat = $infoaddress['lat']; // get the lats and longs
    $lon = $infoaddress['lon'];

    if ($BuildingA = $BuildingD && $RoadNoA = $RoadNoD && $BlockA = $BlockD)
     { // do the logical test

    mysql_query("UPDATE testdata SET lat2='$lat', lon2='$lon' WHERE id='$idD'"); // update the values

     }
     else 
    mysql_query("UPDATE testdata SET lat2='', lon2='' WHERE id='$idD'"); // update the values
 }

?>
```

What happens is that it does update the testdatabase, but for some reason, it has the wrong lats and longs, even when I type in a wrong road and block and building no that don't exist in the address database, it updates it with some lats and longs.

It is important that all 3 conditions be true.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `mysql_` library is deprecated - use PDO or `mysqli_`. Bo something about the indentation. Beware of SQL injection

Comment: Thanks. This is offline, I am just trying to update my database.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You're reading from two tables, and seem to expect the rows to correspond to each other. But there's no `ORDER BY`, so you're reading each table in random order.

Comment: You could probably just write it in two SQL queries and use SQL instead of PHP

Comment: I don't know how to use that, ORDER BY id? Wouldn't that produce the same result cause the two table have different id's? 

My thinking was: I read the first table row by row if lat and long is empty, and then reading the entire second table the whole time (that is why I put it in the loop) to check if there is a corresponding match. Am I wrong?

Comment: But you're not reading the entire second table each time. You're just reading one row of the second table, and comparing it to the row you read of the first table.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to learn. I will read up more about it. I am happy with your solution of doing it in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you're really looking for is an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE testdata t
JOIN address a USING (Building, RoadNo, Block)
SET t.lat2 = a.lat, t.lon2 = a.lon
WHERE t.lat2 = '' AND t.lon2 = ''
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I didn't know you could do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Use `==` instead of `=`

```
 if ($BuildingA == $BuildingD && $RoadNoA == $RoadNoD && $BlockA == $BlockD)
```

instead of

```
if ($BuildingA = $BuildingD && $RoadNoA = $RoadNoD && $BlockA = $BlockD)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, now it doesn't update it when there are wrong values, but it doesn't update it when there are correct values either.